# Unwrapping optional inside of closure using reduce

Tags: swift

I have a quick question that is confusing me a little bit. I made a simple average function that takes an array of optional Ints. I check to make sure the array does not contain a nil value but when I use reduce I have to force unwrap one of the two elements in the closure. Why is it that I only force unwrap the second one (in my case $1!)

```
func average2(array: [Int?]) -> Double? {
    let N = Double(array.count)
    guard N > 0 && !array.contains({$0 == nil}) else {
        return nil
    }

    let sum = Double(array.reduce(0) {$0+$1!})
    let average = sum / N
    return average
}
```

I know it is simple but I would like to understand it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of `reduce` is the sum, which is `0` in the beginning. The second one is the current element of your array which is an optional `Int` and therefore has to be unwrapped.

Your invocation of reduce does this:

```
var sum = 0 // Your starting value (an Int)
for elem in array {
    sum = sum + elem!  // This is the $0 + $1!
}
```

EDIT: I couldn't get a more functional approach than this to work:

```
func average(array: [Int?]) -> Double? {
    guard !array.isEmpty else { return nil }
    let nonNilArray = array.flatMap{ $0 }
    guard nonNilArray.count == array.count else { return nil }
    return Double(nonNilArray.reduce(0, combine: +)) / Double(nonNilArray.count)
}
```

You can also discard the second `guard` if you want something like `average([1, 2, nil])` to return `1.5` instead of `nil`

Comment: So is there a simple way to unwrap it without force unwrapping? Of course I could do a for loop but I am just practicing using more functional techniques.

Comment: Great thank you. I haven't used flatmap before. I will look into it.